# Bug Ajax when I reloaded a div with JQUERY on WordPress Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm developing My First WordPress Plugin but I have a problem when I reload a div with AJAX on Jquery. My Ajax script doesn't when the div has been refreshed with the script.

So, my script perfect work before the refresh div and it's broken, no error logged.

My PHP code:
http://pastebin.com/ehmd7Bvn

My JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.validation').click(function()
{
    alert($(this).data("user"));
    $("#refresh").load(location.href + " #refresh");
});});
```

So the first alert is okay but after .. Doesn't work anymore...

If anyone can help me?

Comment: What does your html look like? Is `.validation` a child element of `#refresh` ?

Comment: Yes it is. example: http://pastebin.com/ZknaS57F

Comment: Then you probably have to use [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) because you are overriding the element on which you bound the event handler

Comment: I tried but this doesn't work :\